# $_REQUEST array blank, but individual values show up

Tags: php, centos

I just built my web server to Centos 7 and now this no longer works:

print_r($_REQUEST);

and shows an empty array...

but this below does if am looking at a specific variable value

echo($_REQUEST["name"]);

it appears it won't let you know all the values of $_REQUEST without knowing the specific name of the variable.

Is this a setting i need to change in PHP.INI or something? Some change in php?

This worked fine with Centos 5, and this was broken when I moved these existing sites over to the new server.

Thanks

Comment: This is suspect - nothing should prevent you from `print_r()` on a superglobal.  A possible thing I would expect could be the setting of `variables_order` in php.ini which could prevent values from `$_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE` being available in `$_REQUEST`, but `print_r()` shouldn't stop working.

Comment: Does `print_r($_POST);` (or $_GET, or whatever gives you the `[name]` values) output anything?